# SQL: Select Description Like X followed by 4 digits

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

Looking to query the following:

```
Select Where Field Like 'Store ####'
```

Where #### is any sequence of 4 digits, but it must be 4 numerical digits.

Comment: Why is this tagged both MySQL and SQL Server?

Answer (score 2):

For SQL Server you would need

```
WHERE Field LIKE 'Store [0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]'
```

Comment: Hi Martin , can you please tell how can we do this if number of digits is large .. eg [0-9]{8} ..?

Comment: @mhasan - Could use `WHERE Field LIKE 'Store ' + REPLICATE('[0-9]',8)`. There is no inbuilt support for quantifiers in the pattern syntax. Though installing CLR regular expressions is another option.

Answer (score 1):

For MySql, you may use [`RLIKE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/regexp.html#operator_regexp):

```
SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE Field RLIKE 'Store [0-9]{4}'
```

Comment: it will select `Store00000000' too

Answer (score 1):

Use regular expresions

```
SELECT * WHERE Field REGEXP 'Store [0-9]{4}'
```

Answer (score 1):

For SQL Server

```
Select * From yourTable
Where Field like 'Store [0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]'
```

Comment: Thanks.  Would adding a wildcard after this still work, ie: GAP [0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]%

Comment: @ZJAY Yes...but now rows having value in field with other characters after the four digits will also be returned.

Answer (score 0):

For `mySQL`, something like:

```
Select Where Field Like 'Store [0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]';
```

See http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/pattern-matching.html

`MSSQL` compatible is unchanged, something like:

```
Select Where Field Like REGEXP 'Store [0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]';
```

See http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/regexp.html